# How to deploy artifacts to Maven Repository (JFrog artifactory) through Jenkins Build Offline?

Tags: jenkins, maven-3, artifactory, jfrog-mission-control

**Context:**
I am trying to do a simple build (not through a pipeline job) on a maven project through Jenkins which is installed in an offline environment (no internet connection). The build happens successfully and I see the HelloMaven.jar successfully deployed to JFrog artifactory which is again installed offline.

**Problem:**
But the overall Jenkins build fails with the reason

> "Build Step:Deploy artifacts to Maven Repository changed build result to FAILURE"

The Jenkins build console output is mentioned as below:

```
Started by user admin
Building in workspace C:\Users\dipakrai\.jenkins\workspace\HelloMaven
Updating https://myownlaptop/svn/HelloMavenDemo/HelloMaven at revision '2017-07-13T11:51:44.844 +0530'
Using sole credentials admin/****** (SVN) in realm <https://myownlaptop.com:443> VisualSVN Server
At revision 6

No changes for https://myownlaptop.com/svn/HelloMavenDemo/HelloMaven since the previous build
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 62532
[HelloMaven] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java" -cp "C:\Users\dipakrai\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-agent-1.11.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar" org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.3" C:\Users\dipakrai\.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-3.7.jar C:\Users\dipakrai\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-1.11.jar C:\Users\dipakrai\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.11.jar 62532
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Users\dipakrai\.jenkins\workspace\HelloMaven\pom.xml deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[HUDSON] Collecting dependencies info
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building HelloMaven 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.3:create (default) @ HelloMaven ---
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --non-interactive info"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Users\dipakrai\.jenkins\workspace\HelloMaven
[INFO] Storing buildNumber: null at timestamp: 1499926911471
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --non-interactive info"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Users\dipakrai\.jenkins\workspace\HelloMaven
[INFO] Storing buildScmBranch: UNKNOWN_BRANCH
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ HelloMaven ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ HelloMaven ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ HelloMaven ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\dipakrai\.jenkins\workspace\HelloMaven\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ HelloMaven ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.2:test (default-test) @ HelloMaven ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\dipakrai\.jenkins\workspace\HelloMaven\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[JENKINS] Recording test results
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:jar (default-jar) @ HelloMaven ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ HelloMaven ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\dipakrai\.jenkins\workspace\HelloMaven\target\HelloMaven.jar to C:\Users\dipakrai\.m2\repository\net\roseindia\maven\quickstart\HelloMaven\1.0-SNAPSHOT\HelloMaven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\dipakrai\.jenkins\workspace\HelloMaven\pom.xml to C:\Users\dipakrai\.m2\repository\net\roseindia\maven\quickstart\HelloMaven\1.0-SNAPSHOT\HelloMaven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ HelloMaven ---
Downloading: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Uploading: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloMaven-1.0-20170713.062154-1.jar
Uploaded: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloMaven-1.0-20170713.062154-1.jar (4 KB at 18.4 KB/sec)
Uploading: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloMaven-1.0-20170713.062154-1.pom
Uploaded: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloMaven-1.0-20170713.062154-1.pom (4 KB at 8.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/maven-metadata.xml
Uploading: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (784 B at 16.3 KB/sec)
Uploading: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/maven-metadata.xml (298 B at 1.5 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.064s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jul 13 11:51:55 IST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/247M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\dipakrai\.jenkins\workspace\HelloMaven\pom.xml to net.roseindia.maven.quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloMaven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\dipakrai\.jenkins\workspace\HelloMaven\target\HelloMaven.jar to net.roseindia.maven.quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-20170713.062154-1/HelloMaven-1.0-20170713.062154-1.jar
Used promoter class: org.jenkinsci.plugins.artifactpromotion.NexusOSSPromotor
channel stopped
Local repository path: [C:\Users\dipakrai\.jenkins\workspace\HelloMaven\target\local-repo]
Started with promotion
Get Artifact and corresponding POM
Checking if POM already exists in releaserepo
POM doesn't exist in release repo, it will be deployed
Downloading: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
##################################################]
Downloaded: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml ( at 31.9 KB/sec)
Uploading: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloMaven-1.0-20170713.055434-15.jar
##################################################]
Uploaded: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloMaven-1.0-20170713.055434-15.jar ( at 17.5 KB/sec)
Uploading: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloMaven-1.0-20170713.055434-15.pom
##################################################]
Uploaded: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloMaven-1.0-20170713.055434-15.pom ( at 9.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/maven-metadata.xml
##################################################]
Downloaded: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/maven-metadata.xml ( at 7.3 KB/sec)
Uploading: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
##################################################]
Uploaded: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml ( at 10.5 KB/sec)
Uploading: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/maven-metadata.xml
##################################################]
Uploaded: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/maven-metadata.xml ( at 2.1 KB/sec)
Skipping deletion of artifact from source repo as requested by user
Maven RedeployPublisher use remote  maven settings from : C:\Users\dipakrai/.m2/settings.xml
[INFO] Deployment in http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1 (id=ArtifactID,uniqueVersion=true)
Deploying the main artifact HelloMaven-1.0-20170713.062154-1.jar
Downloading: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (787 B at 1.9 KB/sec)
Uploading: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloMaven-1.0-20170713.062154-1.jar
Uploading: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloMaven-1.0-20170713.062154-1.pom
ERROR: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact net.roseindia.maven.quickstart:HelloMaven:jar:1.0-20170713.062154-1 from/to ArtifactID (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1): Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloMaven-1.0-20170713.062154-1.jar. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact net.roseindia.maven.quickstart:HelloMaven:jar:1.0-20170713.062154-1 from/to ArtifactID (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1): Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloMaven-1.0-20170713.062154-1.jar. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:143)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.MavenArtifactRecord.deploy(MavenArtifactRecord.java:193)
    at hudson.maven.RedeployPublisher.perform(RedeployPublisher.java:176)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:735)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:676)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1072)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:621)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1760)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:542)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact net.roseindia.maven.quickstart:HelloMaven:jar:1.0-20170713.062154-1 from/to ArtifactID (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1): Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloMaven-1.0-20170713.062154-1.jar. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:420)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:139)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact net.roseindia.maven.quickstart:HelloMaven:jar:1.0-20170713.062154-1 from/to ArtifactID (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1): Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloMaven-1.0-20170713.062154-1.jar. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.put(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:311)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1/net/roseindia/maven/quickstart/HelloMaven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloMaven-1.0-20170713.062154-1.jar. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:631)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:553)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:529)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$PutTaskRunner.run(WagonTransporter.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTransporter.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.put(WagonTransporter.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$PutTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
    ... 16 more
[INFO] Deployment failed after 0.55 sec
Build step 'Deploy artifacts to Maven repository' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

The **pom.xml** file entry for my HelloMaven project is as below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>net.roseindia.maven.quickstart</groupId>
  <artifactId>HelloMaven</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>HelloMaven</name>
   <scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:https://mylaptop/svn/myRepo/</connection>
    </scm>
 <build>
        <finalName>HelloMaven</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                    <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <SCM-Revision>${buildNumber}</SCM-Revision>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</directory>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

 <!-- <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>-->

  <distributionManagement>
      <repository>
        <id>artifactory</id>
        <name>HelloMaven-release</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1</url>
       </repository>
    </distributionManagement> 
</project>
```

The **settings.xml** file for MAVEN **m2** folder is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <!--<localRepository>C:\Users\dipakrai\.m2\repository</localRepository>-->

    <pluginGroups>
        <!-- Nothing is present now-->
    </pluginGroups>

    <proxies>
        <!-- Nothing is present now-->
    </proxies>

  <servers>
    <server>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>{v2akWC7LO8QHuoPFXESAScpHLzTFzcIKG054oyvz/nc=}</password>
      <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>{v2akWC7LO8QHuoPFXESAScpHLzTFzcIKG054oyvz/nc=}</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>artifactory</id>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1</url>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
  </mirrors> 
  <profiles>
    <profile>
    <id>artifadeploymentRepoctory</id>
    <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>HelloMaven-release</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>HelloMaven-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>

    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

For the last four days I have taken trying to fix the issue and went through a number of posts as this [Infrastructure with maven, Jenkins, Nexus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950346/infrastructure-with-maven-jenkins-nexus/11952832#11952832). I am not sure where I am going wrong.
Any clue would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer above by @VonC helped me to fix the issue.  The server id I have entered in the `settings.xml` file and the Jenkins artifactory configuration is a mismatch.
I made the following changes as listed below. 
First, I updated my Jenkins artifactory configuration as shown below. The **REPOSITORY ID** musty exactly match the server id mentioned in the settings.xml file:

```
<server>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>AP447H6DXXJW6WW54BvNBorau5s</password>
      <id>artifactory</id>
</server>
```

And also the repository id entry further below in the **`settings.xml`** file must be the same as server id above:

```
<repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>artifactory</id>
          <name>myproject-release</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo2</url>
</repository>
```

Secondly, *though I haven't tested this explicitly* but it must be that way:
The  entry in the project **pom.xml** file should also be having the same id for repository where the distribution binary has to be released (in this case, the artifactory).

```
<distributionManagement>
      <repository>
        <id>artifactory</id>
        <name>HelloMaven-release</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1</url>
       </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

[image: Jenkins artifactory configuration]

**Alternatively**, since you would have integrated the JFrog artifactory with Jenkins you need not configure the "Deploy artifacts to Maven repository". Instead the below configuration as shown in the screen-shot would deploy your project artifact to the artifactory.

> "Deploy artifact to artifactory"

[image: Deploy artifact to artifactory]

Comment: I muse there is still lot to be explored in the Jenkins/Artifactory set up but more importantly the maven build framework. I am exploring that more with maven. Anybody who has a link to a good tutorial/video/blog where the inner intricacies of maven (such as why central is a keyword in maven which if not abstracted in <mirror> tag then maven would directly contact repo.maven .org, etc..) are discussed threadbare kindly share the same.

Comment: Well done, and nice feedback. +1. I'll have to integrate Jenkins/Artifactory myself at work, so I will follow this question with interest ;)

Comment: @VonC Found an answer to why maven by default calls up the http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 url. It's because of the super-pom.xml https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789488/how-do-you-stop-maven-from-trying-to-access-http-repo-maven-apache-org

Comment: @VonC Merci Bocu! : ) Eureka!

Comment: To those who are lost and tired on Maven but have not given up: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/maven/maven-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

Check what `mvn help:effective-settings` returns in order to double-check your user/password is indeed used.
Double check the username/password match the ones [displayed here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF20/Using+Secured+Passwords+in+Settings.xml), where Atifactory generates the encrypted password.

[image: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/download/attachments/10682798/profile.jpg?version=1&modificationDate=1231133401000&api=v2]

Finally, following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20790377/6309), avoid "`central`" as an id.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer made me relook into the server id I have entered in the settings.xml file and the Jenkins artifactory configuration. There was a mismatch. I have mentioned that in detail in a fresh answer below. The biggest challenge is working offline in a set up like maven+jenkins+artifactory. Yesterday I tried creating a maven project in eclipse through archetype and it just failed as it was not able to connect to repo.org.apache.maven to download the necessary plugins. I wished there could have been an offline version for the apache maven as a binary file to install and work with.